# Activity restart after saving in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database

every time i save data in firebase the activity is restarted , but the data is saved .

```
  public void saveCourses() {

    user.setCourse1(usercourses.get(0));

    user.setCourse2(usercourses.get(1));

    user.setCourse3(usercourses.get(2));

    user.setCourse4(usercourses.get(3));

    user.setCourse5(usercourses.get(4));


    user.setCourse6(usercourses.get(5));
    MyDatabase.child("USERS").child(usernameactionbar).child("Courses").setValue(user);


}
```

and after pressing the button that does the save and intent :

```
// saveCourses();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Courses saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Intent GOTOMYCOURSES = new Intent(chooseCoursesActivity.this , myCourses.class);
                    startActivity(GOTOMYCOURSES);
```

IF i keep commenting the saveCourses recall , everything works fine except for saving data in the Firebase Database , But if i did not comment that out , The data is saved but activity reLaunches .

Comment: is there any error message in android monitor?

Comment: No errors ana every things works fine except for the intent , but the intent works if i comment the method of the save

Comment: I'm in the same case, my activity restarts every Firebase transaction: save data, erase data, update data. Also, it shows a Toast from the previous activity..

Comment: @MisaelGallegosGuzmán so is it a new error without solution or what ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think is right is to use `intent.putExtra ("key", "value");`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have added this **saveCourses()** inside the **ValueEventListener**. So every time a data changes the **startActivity(intent)** is fired. Because when you insert data *it means that you are indeed changing some part of your firebase data structure*, hence the **ValueEventListener** is called and the activity restarts.